# Pass Custom Parameters from webchat control to bot framework

Tags: azure, bots, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

So, I'm currently using this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/preview/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ secret: 'YOUR_BOT_SECRET_FROM_AZURE_PORTAL' })
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and it works fine, however I have multiple QnA Knowledge base for different client applications. SO I would like to pass custom parameter for 'applicationname' to decide the QNA KB in my BOT frame work(V4) in OnTurnAsync method.

I tried

```
var d1 = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token })
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: d1,
         styleSet,
postActivity: activity => {
     var newActivity = Object.assign({}, activity, {channelData: { "userparam": "test" } });
     return dl.postActivity(newActivity);
    }

}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
})();
```

but Context.Activity.ChannelData in bot returning Null

and also tried

```
var d1 = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token })
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: d1,
        user: { id: 'userid', userparam:'test'},
            styleSet

}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
})();
```

still Context.Activity.From.Properties["userparam"] returns Null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Cilent Side

```
var d1 = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token })
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: Object.assign({}, d1, {
     postActivity: activity => {
     var newActivity = Object.assign({}, activity, { channelData: { "param1": "test" } });
     return d1.postActivity(newActivity);
    }
  }),
            styleSet,
            botAvatarInitials: 'CAB',
            userAvatarInitials: 'You'

}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
})();
```

from BOt Framework

```
var channelObj = turnContext.Activity.ChannelData.ToString();
var channeldata = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(channelObj);
var customdata = channeldata["param1"].ToString();
```

Comment: This was really helpful but it overwrites other channelData. I know you're just editing what was originally done in the question but this can cause issues for others.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer provided is helpful but it overwrites channelData. For others finding this answer and just wanting to send custom parameters, this will be helpful:

```
const originalDirectline = props.webchat.createDirectLine({
    token,
})

const directLine = Object.assign({}, originalDirectline, {
    postActivity: (activity: any) => {
        const newActivity = Object.assign({}, activity)
        newActivity.customParam = "custom value"
        return originalDirectline.postActivity(newActivity)
    }
})
```