# How do you implement Azure bot adaptive card?

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, adaptive-cards

My understanding for creating an adaptive card in azure bot is by hard coding it. Is there a better to create an Adaptive card? Because imagine if we have to create 120 cards. We have to hard code files that is like the codes below which is not a good practice. Please help! Thanks

```
 {
   "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "Image",
        "url":"google.image.com",
        "size": "small"
      }
     ],
    "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "title": "Google",
      "url": "google.com"
     }
     ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways you can do this. Given the card:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "id": "img",
            "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                "title": "Google",
                "url": "http://www.google.com"
            },
            "url": "https://imgplaceholder.com/420x320/ff7f7f/333333/fa-image"
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "Google",
            "url": "http://www.google.com"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

Which will render as:

[image]

And given that we're importing it with:

```js
import * as cardJson from './adaptiveCard.json';
```

And then our code looks something like this:

```js
const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(cardJson);
const msg = MessageFactory.text('');
msg.attachments = [card];
await context.sendActivity(msg);
```

#### 1. Edit the JSON directly

If we use this to change the image:

```js
cardJson.body[0].url = 'https://skillbotbuilder.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/skillbotbuilder/skillbotbuilder/1.0/1546976085901/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Icons.Default';
```

we get:

[image]

So, you can use your `.json` as more of a template and then build off of it with javascript. Or:

#### 2. Use a different type of card

[Here's a link to other card types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-rich-cards?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#types-of-cards)

You can then use [CardFactory](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/16f47826ec7fa960b9bb89889b84d222497a54b1/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/cardFactory.ts) to build the cards.

A Hero Card similar to the above would look something like this:

```
const hero = CardFactory.heroCard(
    null,
    CardFactory.images(['https://imgplaceholder.com/420x320/ff7f7f/333333/fa-image']),
    CardFactory.actions([{
        type: 'Action.OpenUrl',
        title: 'Google',
        value: 'Google.com'
    }])
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Is there a way we can get the front website url from the browser in our nodejs azure bot? In case we want to get the www.dev.google.com for testing but when we deploy to production. The url will change to www.google.com. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say. Thanks!

Comment: @khmerforce It's possible, but there's a ton of different ways to do it. With vanilla javascript, look up how to use `ChannelData` in Web Chat to pass variables to the bot. The easiest way, though, would be to use environment variables. Set `ENV="dev"` in your `.env` file and `ENV="prod"` in App Service > Configuration. Then `const url = process.env.ENV == 'prod' ? 'www.google.com' : 'www.dev.google.com'` or something.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't see the .env file. I searched it and it is in the .gitignore. Is that the file? I am using azure bot v4 node js.

Comment: .env file is generally used to store your sensitive info. In many of the the samples, you can see the bot access these variables with `process.env.VARIABLE`. For getting the URL, find a way to get the current URL with javascript, then [pass it to the bot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54343701/10860086)

Comment: Do I need to take it out of .gitignore?

Comment: Nope. It's definitely not a file that you want to be made public (it usually contains passwords/keys), so keep it in .gitignore. When you deploy your bot, you need to make sure that the keys and values in `.env` are also in your Azure > App Service > Configuration.