# Parameters in activity to azure bot

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

We are using Azure Bot's Direct Line (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to send activity to an azure bot.

What is the best/correct way if we want to pass extra parameters in the activity to the bot?

For example, we want to use geolocation to get user's coordinates and pass into the bot. Or, just some parameters from the website that is running the bot.

Can I use Entity ? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.activity.entities?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Schema_Activity_Entities

But how do I set it correctly and read it?
Currently try to set it together with the JSON:

{"type":"message","from":{"id":"741d404e-892c-4231-b69f-ad47fa7ac8de"},"text":"hi","entities":{"testparam":"param123"}}

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Activity.ChannelData Property see the answer to [Pass Custom Parameters from webchat control to bot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54257379/pass-custom-parameters-from-webchat-control-to-bot-framework)

Comment: How about entities?
I tried entities, it can pass the value as well.
Any idea when we should use entity or channeldata?
Thanks

Comment: Doc about entities says "Gets or sets represents the entities that were mentioned in the message.". So no, you should not use this field

Comment: Any idea what is this entities that were mentioned in the message about? When should we use it? Does it has anything to do with LUIS' entities? Thanks.

Comment: How about value? Is it a better choice to send a generic parameter?