# Passing variables from webchat client to bot framework

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have a requirement to pass an ID from webchat client to the bot. I did my research and found this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54257379/pass-custom-parameters-from-webchat-control-to-bot-framework) where @justin-harris mentions the following code

```
const originalDirectline = props.webchat.createDirectLine({
    token,
})

const directLine = Object.assign({}, originalDirectline, {
    postActivity: (activity: any) => {
        const newActivity = Object.assign({}, activity)
        newActivity.customParam = "custom value"
        return originalDirectline.postActivity(newActivity)
    }
})
```

This works in a sense and I am able to receive the ID in my bot but whenever I send a message from my webchat client as a user, it goes twice (the first message fails and the second succeeds). I am not sure as to why it is doing that. Would really appreciate if somebody sheds some light on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out via a middleware that we can pass during store initialization. Here's the solution for any future souls:

```
const store = useMemo(
() =>
  createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => (next) => (action) => {
    if (action.type === "DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY") {
      action = simpleUpdateIn(
        action,
        ["payload", "activity", "channelData", "yourVariableHere"],
        () => "Your data here"
      );
    }
    return next(action);
  }),
[]
);
```

I am using a package called [simple-update-in](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-update-in) to modify the object. You should be able to access it on the bot end via `action.payload.activity.channelData`

Comment: A better option is to use "WEB_CHAT/SEND_ACTIVITY" (or one of the other options: SEND_POSTBACK, SEND_MESSAGE_BACK, or SEND_EVENT). As noted in the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/b.piggyback-on-outgoing-activities#sample---piggyback-data-on-every-outgoing-activity) that demonstrates "piggybacking" on an activity: _This is just a proof of concept thus should not be used in production and lacks security considerations._

Comment: @StevenKanberg Thank you for the reply. So is using WEBCHAT/SEND_ACTIVITY safer when it comes to security considerations?

I am not passing any sensitive info though. Just a plain ID which is visible in the URL anyway.

Comment: in terms of security, there is no difference. In one instance (POST_ACTIVITY), you are editing an already existing activity (e.g. a “hello” that was entered into Web Chat’s send box). In the other instance (SEND_ACTIVITY), you are creating a new activity (e.g. user clicks “get location” button on hosting web page which generates the “send activity” function in Web Chat). Regardless, all activities are encrypted by Direct Line, which Web Chat uses under the hood.